# ReferenceError: require is not defined [javascript]

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am building a firefox extension. Whenever a given url loads in the firefox browser, the browser should give alert message. I used page-load API. but I'm getting an error: require is not defined. I'm very new to this page-load. Help me to fix this error!!!

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.mozilla.org",
  contentScript: 'window.alert("Page matches ruleset");'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `var pageMod = require("page-mod");` ? (ie. without the `sdk/` prefix)

EDIT: the above isn't correct for the latest version of the SDK. If it's working for you then maybe you have an old version. Try updating.

Comment: Error is not coming without sdk prefix. but it's not giving alert message when m loading given URL

Comment: my answer was correct for version 1.11 of the SDK. The latest however is 1.13. Maybe you need to upgrade.

Comment: My sdk version is 1.13....yeah you are right it's not working now...earlier I did some mistake...and one more thing I have included this page load code in my XUL file.